# Add a blank item into DataCombo in VB6

Tags: vb6

I have written the following code to bind a datacombo

```
With dtcType
        Set .RowSource = recType
            .ListField = "Type"
            .BoundColumn = "TypeId"
End With
```

**I want to add a blank item at the top of the DataCombo** (After binding the datacombo - so users can also select a blank item). How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I remember there is no direct method to add item do `DataCombo`.
You may consider two options.

If your SQL looks more a less like this:

```
SELECT Id, Code FROM my_table
```

You can add artifictial record using `SELECT` without `FROM` clause combined with `UNION`

```
SELECT -1 As Id, '' As Code 
UNION ALL
SELECT Id, Code FROM my_table
```

The second option is replace `DataCombo` with `Combobox` and populate items with method like this one:

```
Public Sub Populate(ByRef pData As ADODB.Recordset, _
                ByVal pIdField As String, _
                ByVal pDataField As String, _
                Optional pEmptyItem As Boolean = False, _
                Optional pEmptyItemId As Long = -2, _
                Optional pEmptyItemCaption As String = "")

    If m_ComboboxControl Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    If pEmptyItem Then
        m_ComboboxControl.AddItem pEmptyItemCaption
        m_ComboboxControl.ItemData(m_ComboboxControl.NewIndex) = pEmptyItemId
    End If   

    With pData

        If Not (.BOF And .EOF) Then
            Do While Not .EOF
                Select Case TypeName(pData.Fields(pDataField).Value)
                    Case "Date"
                        m_ComboboxControl.AddItem Format(pData.Fields(pDataField), "DD-MM-YYYY")
                    Case Else
                        m_ComboboxControl.AddItem pData.Fields(pDataField)
                End Select
                m_ComboboxControl.ItemData(m_ComboboxControl.NewIndex) = CLng(pData.Fields(pIdField))

                .MoveNext
            Loop
        End If


    End With

End Sub
```